# aggregate function Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

I am working with Pyspark 2.2 rn,
my code crashes by this function and I don't understand why it's crashed on ->

*code*

```
import Pyspark.sql.functions as F
t.withColumns('column_name',
              F.expr("aggregate(column, '', (acc, x) -> acc || concat(x, 4) ','))"))
```

error like - "extraneous input '>' expecting 'all of sql functions'"

ty for ur help

Comment: Your expression does look weird. What are you trying to achieve there? Do you have an example of your input and your expected output?

Comment: `aggregate` function is available since Spark 2.4 but you're using version 2.2. Also, you have some extra parentheses in the expression `concat(x, 4) ','))`

Comment: @blackbishop ty, mb I can change this aggregate func to smth that spark 2.2 has? I am new in spark, idk all functionality

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions.

1. Remove the `','))`: those parentheses are unmatched.
2. Use either `…||…` or `concat(…,…)`; no need for both.
3. Because the column expression contains `>` and the column is not aliased, spark is trying to turn the expression itself into the column name, but column names cannot contain `>`, as the OP's error message alludes to.

   **Solution: Alias the column.**

   (See screenshot. Yes, the screenshot uses spark SQL instead of pyspark, but the OP's issue is with the spark SQL snippet within the pyspark.)

[image: Spark SQL columns with the function aggregate must be aliased]